# How to use go-sqlmock WithArgs() with a variable number of arguments?

Tags: go

I use go-sqlmock (https://godoc.org/github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock) to test a function that receives a variable number of arguments (I simplified the function for the sake of simplicity and stripped out most of the code):

```
func getHits(db *sql.DB, actions ...string) (hits []Hit, err error) {
   // ...
   query := `select * from table where action in (?,?)`
   rows, err := db.Query(query, actions)
   // ...
}
```

The tests look like that:

```
// rows := ...
actions := []string{"click", "event"}
mock.ExpectQuery(`^select .*`).WithArgs(actions).WillReturnRows(rows)
hits, err := getHits(db, actions...)
if mockErr := mock.ExpectationsWereMet(); mockErr != nil {
    log.Fatalf("there were unfulfilled expections: %s", mockErr)
}
```

Then I get this output:

```
2017/12/21 10:38:23 there were unfulfilled expections: there is a remaining expectation which was not matched: ExpectedQuery => expecting Query or QueryRow which:
- matches sql: '^select .*'
- is with arguments:
  0 - [click event]
- should return rows: ...
```

If I change the tests like this:

```
mock.ExpectQuery(`^select .*`).WithArgs(actions[0], actions[1]).WillReturnRows(rows)
```

Then I get this output:

```
2017/12/21 10:44:41 there were unfulfilled expections: there is a remaining expectation which was not matched: ExpectedQuery => expecting Query or QueryRow which:
- matches sql: '^select .*'
- is with arguments:
  0 - click
  1 - event
- should return rows:
```

The only I can make it pass is by calling :

```
db.Query(query, actions[0], actions[1])
```

which is what I obviously don't want to do as I don't know the number of actions...

Does anyone have an idea on how I could fix or debug this ?

Comment: Does `actions...` not work?

Comment: @Flimzy nope; the compiler complains : `cannot use actions (type []string) as type []driver.Value in argument to mock.ExpectQuery("^select .*").WithArgs`

Comment: Convert `actions` to type `[]driver.Value` then.

Comment: @Flimzy unfortunately this yields exactly the same output as in case 2.

Comment: Sorry, which is case 2?

Comment: The second one; it outputs the same as with `...WithArgs(actions[0], actions[1])...`

Comment: You didn't include the full output in that case, so I'm not sure what's missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to fix my problem : If I convert the slice of strings to a slice of interfaces for db.Query, it works just fine:

```
boundValues := make([]interface{}, len(actions))

for i, val := range actions {
    boundValues[i] = val
}

rows, err := db.Query(query, boundValues...)
```

Then for the tests:

```
mock.ExpectQuery(`^select .*`).WithArgs(actions[0], actions[1]).WillReturnRows(rows)
```

NOTE: passing just `db.Query(query, actions...)` does not work; this results in `cannot use actions (type []string) as type []interface {} in argument to db.Query`

Answer (score 5):

Accepted answer using `[]interface{}` would work for string but it can throw an error for other types.

**Short answer**

```
actions := []driver.Value{"click", "event"}
mock.ExpectQuery(`^select .*`).WithArgs(actions...).WillReturnRows(rows)
```

**Long answer**

The argument requires `driver.Value` [reference](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock/blob/9d03611ad1ffde3b3b63004e31c67f237bc6e7c3/expectations.go#L136) and driver.Value can be one of these [types](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Value):

- int64
- float64
- bool
- []byte
- string
- time.Time

so, the correct answer is

```
actions := []driver.Value{"click", "event"}
mock.ExpectQuery(`^select .*`).WithArgs(actions...).WillReturnRows(rows)
```

Comment: if int64 is in the types allowed in driver.Value, then why won't a []int64 work?

Comment: You could do  []driver.Value{<int64>, <int64>,...}

Answer (score 3):

A much cleaner solution would be to use this.

```
/* Prepare database mock */
type AnyNumber struct{}

// Match satisfies sqlmock.Argument interface
func (a AnyNumber) Match(v driver.Value) bool {
    _, ok := v.(float64)
    return ok
}
```

And then use `AnyNumber{}` as the argument in `WithArgs`

Here is the reference in the docs [Click Here](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock#matching-arguments-like-timetime)